# How to prove a nature of arc cosine (Chebyshev polynomials)

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry, complex-numbers, proof-writing, integers

The following equation seems to work well for complex-extended arc cosine.

$ n,k \in \mathbb{N}$

$$n \cdot \cos^{-1}(k) = \cos^{-1} \left( \sum_{m=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}(-1)^m \cdot \frac{n(n-m-1)!}{m!(n-2m)!} \cdot 2^{n-2m-1} \cdot k^{n-2m} \right)$$

For example, let $n=5,\ k=2$
\begin{eqnarray*}
LHS\ &=\ &5 \cos^{-1}(2) \\
&\simeq\ &6.584789484624083i\\
\\
RHS\ &=\ &\cos^{-1} \left( \sum_{m=0}^{\lfloor \frac{5}{2} \rfloor}(-1)^m \cdot \frac{5(5-m-1)!}{m!(5-2m)!} \cdot 2^{5-2m-1} \cdot 2^{5-2m} \right) \\
&=\ &\cos^{-1} \left(\frac{5\cdot4!}{5!} \cdot 2^4 \cdot 2^5 - \frac{5\cdot3!}{3!} \cdot 2^2 \cdot 2^3 + \frac{5\cdot2!}{2!}\cdot 2\right) \\
&=\ &\cos^{-1}  (362)\\
&\simeq\ &6.584789484624083i
\end{eqnarray*}

I want proof or counterexamples. Thank you.

---

8/3 add

The equation means the following expression.

$$ n \cdot \cos^{-1}(x) = \cos^{-1}(T_n(x))$$

$T_n(x)\ $is Chebyshev polynomials that is expressed by following equation.

$$ T_n(x) = \cos(nt),\ (x=\cos(t))$$

I'm not sure because it involves complex numbers, but it seems that the form can be derived by formula conversion.

Comment: Read Wikipedia [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) $T_n(x)$ of the first kind.

Comment: Should something be said about the branch cut of the arc cosine in the complex plane?

Comment: $\mathrm{\cos^{-1}(362)=5cos^{-1}(2)}$ is true. The inverse cosine function has this [continuation](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ArcCos/05/).  The main definition of it is [this](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ArcCos/02/).

Comment: Also if $$\mathrm{y\,cos^{-1}(x)=cos^{-1}(z)\implies z=cos(y\,cos^{-1}(z)}$$ which is indeed the definition of the Chebyshev polynomials. This means one if the series is the expansion for z.